# Why is this variable "nil" even though I have an "if" statement that checks it not to be

Tags: ios, swift, null, uiimageview, option-type

Even though I check whether `self.photoImageView.image != nil`, I am still getting a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error when I try to `applyBlurEffect` in the penultimate line.

Do you know how to reconcile this?

```
if (output?.getAccel() == true){
        if (output?.getImage() != nil){
            if (self.photoImageView.image != nil){
                println(photoImageView.image)
                var blurredImage = self.applyBlurEffect(self.photoImageView.image!)
                self.photoImageView.image = blurredImage
            }
```

For context, I have a `photoImageView`, and when an "accelerometer button" is plugged into that `photoImageView`, this function takes that image, blurs it, and updates the image as a blurred image.

Also when I print `photoImageView.image`, it returns
`Optional(<UIImage: 0x174087d50> size {1340, 1020} orientation 0 scale 1.000000)`. Therein may lie the problem but I need a little help to solve it.

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work. I think the problem has to do with something you're doing in applyBlurEffect, not because unwrapping image gives you nil.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift you have to use *optional binding* to make sure that an optional is not nil. In this case you should do something like this:

```
if let image = self.photoImageView.image {
    //image is set properly, you can go ahead
} else {
    //your image is nil
}
```

It is a very important concept in Swift so you can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330).

**UPDATE**: As @rdelmar stated, *optional binding* is not obligatory here, checking for `nil` should also be enough. Personally I prefer using optional binding though. One of its benefits is the `multiple optional binding` instead of checking all optionals for nil:

```
if let constantName = someOptional, anotherConstantName = someOtherOptional {
    statements
}
```

Comment: Thanks about this one, fixed it.

Comment: This is not true. You don't *have* to use optional binding, though it's a good pattern to use. Checking the optional for equality to nil in an if statement should also work.